# MWE2 Workflow component with Scala language

Tags: java, scala, scala-ide, oaw, mwe

I'm trying to write a MWE2 workflow component using scala language.
Below is the scala code:

```
package com.ford.modelling.workflow

import org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.{IWorkflowComponent, IWorkflowContext}

class SayHello extends IWorkflowComponent {
  var message : String = null;

  def preInvoke {}
  def invoke(ctx : IWorkflowContext) { System.out.println(message) } 
  def postInvoke {}
}
```

and below is the workflow code:

```
module com.ford.modelling.workflow.SomeWorklow

SayHello {}
```

I can't figure out why does this workflow complain for error:

```
'com.ford.modelling.workflow.SayHello' does not have a public default constructor.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume that the scala IDE plugin does not mimic the java protocol completely, e.g. the IType does not expose a no-args constructor. You may want to ask the scale folks about it.

The error message should vanish as soon as you add a default constructor explicitly. Does that make sense?

A quick google search indicated that there probably no syntax for a default constructor so I'd assume it's a scala tooling problem. Does the problem occur at runtime, too?

Comment: hoe can I add the constructor explicitly? I don't know the syntax.

Comment: There is nothing in the problems list but it is underlined in the editor.